# Prove $A+(B+C) = (A+B) +C$ using the definition of $A+B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Define the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$, written $A+B$, by $A+B=(A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$.

Prove the following statement:

f.$A+(B+C) = (A+B) +C$

We need to define the symmetric difference of $A+(B+C) = (A+B) +C$

$A+(B+C) = A+[(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)]$

$(A+B) +C = [(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)]+ C$

We need to use the associative law for set theory which is $(A \cap B) \cap C = A \cap (B \cap C) $ and $(A \cup B) \cup C = A \cup (B \cup C)$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
A+(B+C)\\
A+[(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)]\\
(A \cup [(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)]) \setminus (A \cap [(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)])\\
([(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus (A \cup B \cap C)]) \setminus ( [A \cap (B \cup C) \setminus A \cap (B \cap C)])\\
\end{array}
$$

And then I get stuck afterwards because the middle part of the last line is pure garbage with no substitution whatsoever .

Using the property of $A \backslash B - A \cap B'$ huh?

$(B \cup C) \backslash (B \cap C) = (B \cup C) \backslash (B \cap C)'$

and then I need to prove that $A \cup B \backslash B = ( A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A)$...wait how?! I don't understand this part fully.

$ A + B + C = [[(A \cap B)' \cup (B \cap A')] \cap C'] \cup [ C \cap [A \cap B') \cup ( B \cap A'))]$

but then where do I go from here?  Do I just substitute back?
Moreover, why do I need to use the property of $A \backslash B - A \cap B'$

Comment: You mistake is that $A \cup (B\setminus C) \neq (A\cup B)\setminus(A\cup C)$, when going from line 2 to 3.

Comment: where is the mistake? Is it in the cluster with the last line having the middle part being nonsense or when I tried the set property?

Comment: The transition from line 2 to 3 is erroneous.

Comment: the line after $A+ [ B \cup C \backslash B \cap C]$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant line 3 to 4, the left hand side.

Comment: This one? $([(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus (A \cup B \cap C)]) \setminus ( [A \cap (B \cup C) \setminus A \cap (B \cap C)])\\$

Comment: Yes, Note how in line 3 you have $\text{expression} \supset A$ and the line 4 expression has empty intersection with $A$.

Comment: errrrr yeah....so how do I fix it... does the middle part of the fourth line become an empty set or disappears in its entirety?

Comment: Just _don't_ distribute $\cup$ and $\cap$ over $\setminus$, maybe it helps to write
$$A\setminus B = A\cap B^C$$

Comment: $(A \cup [(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)]) \setminus (A \cap [(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)])$....but since $A \backslash B = A \cap B'$ do I replace $ A \cup B$ and $ A \cap B$ with the set property?

Comment: If I can't distribute which by the looks of it produced a very disastrous result. How do I apply the $A\setminus B = A\cap B^C$

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to give a double-containment argument, i.e. to prove
$$x \in A+(B+C) \quad \text{if and only if} \quad x \in (A+B)+C$$
When you unpack the definitions, you'll end up seeing that both are equivalent to the assertion that $x$ lies in one of $A$, $B$ or $C$ and, if it lies in more than one, then it lies in all three. (But you should do this.)

To start you off: if $x \in A+(B+C)$ then $x \in A$ or $x \in B+C$, but $x \not \in A \cap (B+C)$. If $x \in B+C$ then $x \in B$ or $x \in C$ but $x \not \in B \cap C$; hence the only way that we can have $x \in B \cap C$ is if $x \in A$. So... over to you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose x belongs to both A and B.  Then x does not belong to (A+B).

Suppose x belongs to A, but not to B.  Then x belongs to (A+B).

Suppose x does not belong to A, but belongs to B.  Then x belongs to (A+B).

Suppose x does not belong to A, nor belongs to B.  Then x does not belong to (A+B).

Consequently, we can describe (A+B) by the following matrix where "0" indicates not belonging, and 1 indicates belonging:

```
+
A/B  0   1
0    0   1
1    1   0
```

Now, the logical equivalence E operation of propositional calculus has the following matrix:

```
E
p/q  0   1
0    1   0
1    0   1
```

Logical equivalence associates in the sense that for all p, q, and r
[pE(qEr)]=[(pEq)Er].  Logical equivalence and symmetric difference are isomorphic.  Consequently, symmetric difference associates also.